# OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable')

Tags: python, unix

I'm trying to make a POST request to an API hosted in a remote UNIX server using the following code:

```
 response = requests.post(f'{base_endpoint}/{endpoint_path}?api_key=**',
 headers=headers,
 data=json.dumps(data))`
```

It returns me the error:

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xx.xx.xx.xx', port=xx): Max retries exceeded with url: /endpoint_path?api_key=** (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable')))

What does this error mean and what do I need to fix it?

I'm able to make a connection to the UNIX server using Putty, and able to send the POST request using Postman successfully, but not from the code.

Comment: 1. Did you run the code on your local machine?
2. Did you use a proxy?
3. Check the headers, perhaps you missed something.
4. Check the data you send, perhaps you send the wrong data.